# Where do I ask questions on Kindle Paperwhite?

Tags: discussion

Is ebooks,  a forum to ask specific questions on kindle paperwhite?  For ex, I have a ebook on my kindle which is 9 volumes combined into one? As I am towards the end of the ebook (>90%) the Kindle reboots on a page next. Where do I ask a solution to this? I already asked the question here :-) but which is the right place for such questions? I also had a question on the best way to index such multi volume books.

Answer (score 2):

Paperwhite is a pretty narrow topic -- and you might find better luck on a Kindle-oriented forum.

But I have noticed a fair number of questions posed here which are device specific.

Answer (score 2):

Yes the is the correct site on Stack Exchange to ask questions about kindle paperwhite or any e-reader.

We don't have many answers on this as we are not getting the volume of questions so I don't know if you will get an answer,